# Unable to locate repositories after adding nexus to settings.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I just recently created my own nexus repository manager, and when I went to add it to my own project's settings.xml file, now none of my dependencies are resolving. Here is my POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>projectname</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>projectname</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://nexus.repo.placeholder/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.repo.placeholder/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>projectname</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

            <repository>
                <id>minebench-repo</id>
                <url>https://repo.minebench.de/</url>
            </repository>
        <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.minuskube.inv</groupId>
        <artifactId>smart-invs</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.themoep</groupId>
            <artifactId>inventorygui</artifactId>
            <!--The following version may not be the latest. Check it before using.-->
            <version>1.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

However, no longer are my dependencies resolving in my pom anymore.

settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://repo.template/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>

    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

</settings>
```

All of my credentials are correct to connect to the Nexus system and such as well. Could it be because I have defined a new settings.xml? Do I need to put something in it to fetch the proper repositories for other dependencies as well?

Comment: I actually just fixed it by overriding the default repo to the same .m2 repository that I have been using forever, but now when I go to build, it is trying to download the apache maven resources plugin from the nexus system. Furthermore, there are duplicate dependencies in my maven and it is throwing an error saying that it can't find the descriptors even though it resolved the dependencies in the POM. how do I get rid of the other duplicate ones?

Comment: Check the repositories you have defined in your pom file ... move those definitions into your nexus..and remove them from your pom file. Apart from that how are you calling Maven? And where have you located your settings.xml file.

Comment: @khmarbaise I added my own settings.xml file into the project and defined it in the preferences of IntelliJ. What do you mean move the definitions into my nexus? I am new to all of this nexus stuff.